# how to add ARC in between of project

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, automatic-ref-counting

I am creating iPhone app and in between I need to use [`SDWebImage`](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). For this I need to use ARC.

Any idea how to add ARC in between in project?

**Note:** In one file I have below content.

```
#if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
#error SDWebImage is ARC only. Either turn on ARC for the project or use -fobjc-arc flag
#endif
```

Where should I add `-fobjc-arc` flag?

Comment: You can opt for No-ARC in some files.

Comment: check [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1), they explain how ARC works but also how to enable it in a non-ARC project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select Project Form Project Manager
  |
  | 
  Targets
       |
       |
     Build Phases
          |
          |
        Compile Sources
                |
                |
            Select File that you Want to crate as ARC. (You can also Select Multiple File name from here)
                        |
                        |
                    Press "ENTER" key
                           |
                           |
                      Popup Box/Window is displayed 
                               |
                               |
                            Write here - '-fno-objc-arc'
                                    |
                                    |
                                And again Press 'ENTER' key.

Your selected file is being ARC.
```

Comment: Error : `clang: error: no such file or directory: '__unsafe_unretained'`

Answer (score 1):

```
Change from build settings

Project->Build setting->Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting  SET YES

If you need to remove ARC then Go to  Project->Build Phases->compile sources then find your file Which you need to remove ARC then set compile source '-fno-objc-arc'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using xcode 4.6 then Select  your target `Target`->`Build Settings`and find **Apple LLVM compiler 4.2** see in this section if **Objective-c Automatic Reference Counting** is set to **YES**, if not then just set it to YES. For older version of XCode you could change for `Apple LLVM compiler 3.0`

Answer (score 0):

In top of xcode

edit->refactor->then chose convert to Arc

Answer (score 0):

try this[image: look into the image as shown add -fobjc-arc flag flag-]

hope this will solve your prob..

Answer (score 0):

Edit → Refactor → Convert to Objective-C ARC.

Here’s the documentation on how to deal with any migration issues:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html