# ios app crashes because of XMPPMessageArchiving

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xmppframework

I added Message Archiving for XMPP chat im my app.

After that, my app crashes when I send/receive message in XMPP chat. App crashes only when I run it on device without connect to laptop (xcode). When I debug the app in xcode, there are no crashes.

I connected all necessary XMPP classes and directories to my project.

I setup XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage and XMPPMessageArchiving instances:

```
xmppMessageArchivingStorage = [XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage sharedInstance];

xmppMessageArchivingModule = [[XMPPMessageArchiving alloc] initWithMessageArchivingStorage:xmppMessageArchivingStorage];
[xmppMessageArchivingModule setClientSideMessageArchivingOnly:YES];
```

I activate XMPPMessageArchiving instance:

```
[xmppMessageArchivingModule activate:xmppStream];
```

and add delegate:

```
[xmppMessageArchivingModule addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

Also, I do:

```
[xmppMessageArchivingModule removeDelegate:self];
[xmppMessageArchivingModule deactivate];
xmppMessageArchivingModule = nil;
xmppMessageArchivingStorage = nil;
```

What it the reason of crashes?

Answer (score 2):

Resolved:

add compile flag

> -fobjc-arc

to XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage.m
and XMPPMessageArchiving.m

how to add flag is here [how to add ARC in between of project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15476067/how-to-add-arc-in-between-of-project)