# How to Turn off ARC for a framework if files of that framework are not seen under compile sources?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa

i have compiled Pantomime framework and when i add it to my project it shows the following error:

Pantomime.framework/Versions/A/Headers/CWCacheManager.h:40:13: ARC forbids Objective-C objects in structs or unions

How can i turn off ARC or solve this issue because this file CWCacheManager is not showing in compile sources.

All Suggestions are welcome. Thanx in Advance

Answer (score 1):

This is basic step :

```
Select Project Form Project Manager
  |
  | 
  Targets
       |
       |
     Build Phases
          |
          |
        Compile Sources
                |
                |
            Select File that you Want to crate as ARC. (You can also Select Multiple File name from here)
                        |
                        |
                    Press "ENTER" key
                           |
                           |
                      Popup Box/Window is displayed 
                               |
                               |
                            Write here - '-fno-objc-arc'
                                    |
                                    |
                                And again Press 'ENTER' key.

Your selected file is being ARC OFF.
```

Comment: *"Select File that you Want to crate as ARC"* ??? - You should adjust your answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15476142/1187415 to this question - or better just vote to close as a duplicate.